# invalid boundry region to join faces

Tags: vertices, edit-mode

*Please note that I'm new to Blender.*

I was watching tutorials on YouTube. In the second tutorial I watched, there is part about modeling the default *cube*. It says to put the cube in *Edit Mode* then key <kbd>X</kbd> for the *Deletion Pop Up Menu* and select *Dissolve Verticies*. However, when I select *dissolve vertices*, I get the error message **Invalid boundary region to join faces**. That message is not shown in the tutorial. How can I fix this?

Comment: link to tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the vertices you are located on more than one axes.
All the vertices have to be on a single axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *Dissolve* tools are quite complex, having very specific functions that can be very powerful when used correctly.

## Dissolve Tools Explained

### Dissolve Vertices

This is for taking an extra vertex out of a one dimensional line. It comes in handy in one main case; modeling off of a reference image.

When one models a complex shape off of an image, they first <kbd>E</kbd>xtrude and <kbd>G</kbd>rab to trace the edge of the object. Then they select 4 vertices at a time in a roughly rectangular pattern and key <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face. Sometimes, when trying to create a face, there might be an extra vertex in between those 4 that needs to go. This would be the time to use the *Dissolve Vertices* feature.

[image]

*Two faces made and a third threatens to be a pentagon, so one vertex is dissolved.*

### Dissolve Edges

This is for taking an edge loop out by joining the faces on either side of it. The main case this is good for is for getting rid of loop cuts in models, complex or basic.

When one is modeling, I've found the five primary tools that every modeler needs to be able to use to be the following in this order:

1. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Translate (<kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>)
4. **Loop cut** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
5. Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>)

Obviously, we're going to focus on the *Loop cut* tool. This creates loops of vertices and is generally the cleaner, faster, neater alternative to *<kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide*. Sometimes, though, one can create too many loop cuts, or not want an edge loop in a certain place. They then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> select a loop cut, key <kbd>X</kbd>, and select *Dissolve Edges*.

[image]

*Center edge loop not wanted; dissolved.*

### Dissolve Faces

This is for merging multiple faces into one. It is mainly used for clearing up topology. In a way, it is very similar to the *Dissolve Edges* tool, except it chooses the edges based on the faces, rather than you.

When one is cleaning up topology after a *Subdivision* or just simply joining faces to create something new, the *Dissolve Faces* tool may provide an easier alternative to the *Dissolve Edges* tool, which is mostly for whole multidimensional (x+y, x+z, y+z, x+y+z) edge loops.

[image]

*Some faces need to be joined for aesthetic appearances and later UV mapping; dissolved into each other.*

## Your Situation

Without a link to your tutorial, it is impossible to figure out what you want to do. I have done my best to explain how to properly use each of the dissolve tools, and I hope that you can figure out from here which one works the best. Lastly, I included the .blend file in which I filmed all of the gifs.

[image]